# Call custom_module phtml file in cms page

Tags: magento2, phtml, cms-pages

How to call a phtml file in cms page. my phtml file is located under the path
\app\code\Testing\Helloworld\view\frontend\templates\helloworld.phtml.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Testing_Helloworld::helloworld.phtml"}}
```

you can use `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` block class to call custom phtml files with out define block class.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code in cms page, If you want to call phtml with in cms page.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Testing_Helloworld::helloworld.phtml"}}
```

Comment: accept answer @muthu krishnan